# Help me identify a science fiction story from the 60's or 70's. It begins with some post-human types having a "ball"

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, transhuman

It is then explained that the "ball" is about a mile in diameter.  I don't remember anything about the plot – just this opening gag line.  It was in an anthology I read as a kid. Possibly by a well-known author.  Of course the terms trans-human and post-human aren't used, but the concept is there.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  If you can come up with any other details - even if you can remember what the cover of the anthology looked like or any of the other stories in it - it would help a lot.  Check out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) to see if they can help you recall anything else to [edit] in.

Comment: _Dancers at the End of Time_ by Michael Moorcock immediately comes to mind.

Comment: @Spencer - They certainly had some epic-scale objects, but I don't remember a giant ball. Maybe in one of the later books of the series?

Comment: Yes, I think you're on to something, Spencer.  Did Moorcock write short stories in that universe or am I thinking about a novel?

Comment: @Scramjet Yes, there were several.  I need to dig.

Comment: @Spencer Looking at descriptions of the End of Time, the story being about decadent immortals who like to throw parties sounds about right.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a line like this in [Legends from the End of Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dancers_at_the_End_of_Time#Legends_from_the_End_of_Time) by Michael Moorcock.

> My Lady Charlotina's Ball must have been at least a mile in circumference, set against the soft tones of a summer twilight, red-gold and transparent so that, as one approached, the guests who had already arrived could be seen standing upon the inner wall, clad in creations extravagant even at the End of Time.

The *Ball* is literally a ball:

> The Ball itself was inclined to roll a little, but those inside it were undisturbed; their footing was firm, thanks to My Lady Charlotina's artistry. The Ball was entered by means of a number of sphincterish openings, placed more or less at random in its outer wall. At the very centre of the Ball, on a floating platform, sat an orchestra comprised of the choicest musicians, out of a myriad of ages and planets, from My Lady's great menagerie (she specialized, currently, in artists).

This is the fourth book in Moorcock's Dancers at the End of Time series, and that fits the description of *post humans* since the protagonists are immortal decadents with nothing better to do than mess around and indulge their fantasies.

Comment: _Legends_ is an anthology of previously published novellas.  This one is called "Pale-Roses" and was originally in _[New Worlds 7](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?23797)_.  I read it in _OMNI_ but I can't find the listing.

Comment: Thanks @John Rennie!  I must have picked up the 4th book unknowingly.