# Eternity - the great big *something* ball

Tags: story-identification

Many years ago I read a short story with a title along the lines of *The great big* something *ball*. The narrator was immortal and faced the problem of facing up to the huge amount of time ahead.  The metaphor for this was a small ball avoiding being crushed by a huge ?metal? ball.  Does anyone know the title of this story?

I think I probably read it in the 1980s plus or minus a decade, almost certainly in a book of science fiction short stories.  If I remember it right, the narrator seemed to deal with eternity by going to a lot of tea parties (think Edwardian England).  The metaphor was along the lines of the small ball keeping to the corners of a room to avoid being crushed by the giant ball.

Comment: Possibly a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/231859/20774 - The Dancers at the End of Time have a literal big ball.

Comment: [isfdb doesn't find any short stories resembling the title you remember](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/adv_search_results.cgi?USE_1=title_title&O_1=contains&TERM_1=great&C=AND&USE_2=title_title&O_2=contains&TERM_2=ball&USE_3=title_title&O_3=exact&TERM_3=&USE_4=title_title&O_4=exact&TERM_4=&USE_5=title_title&O_5=exact&TERM_5=&USE_6=title_title&O_6=exact&TERM_6=&ORDERBY=title_title&ACTION=query&START=0&TYPE=Title)

Comment: The closest I can find is [The Game with the Big Heavy Ball](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?62660) but I don't have the story and cannot find anything about it on the Internet.

Comment: @John Rennie  Thanks - I'm fairly sure that's it.  I think I read it in New Writings in SF 30

Answer (score 5):

This is a long shot since it is based on the title, but the OP agrees that it could be [The Game with the Big Heavy Ball](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?62660) by Brian Aldiss.

[One book](https://books.google.com/books?id=4jFaAAAAMAAJ&q=%22The%20Game%20with%20the%20Big%20Heavy%20Ball%22&dq=%22The%20Game%20with%20the%20Big%20Heavy%20Ball%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjowqGhq6zrAhWwp1kKHYFWCpIQ6AEwAXoECAkQAQ) describes it like this:

> In a recent story, 'The Game with the Big Heavy Ball' (78), Aldiss made the relationship between immortality and the games of the psyche more explicit by making it uncertain whether the two children, Billie and Bathsheba, are immortals trapped forever in infancy , or paranoid schizophrenics with their dreams of psychonic attacks by aliens.

The date matches, since it was published in 1977, and the title kind of matches, but I do not have any of the anthologies that the story has appeared in so I cannot check if the story matches the rest of the description further.